# Swift enum multiple generic types involving depending protocols

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-extension

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    func someFunc() -> Any
}

protocol ProtocolB: ProtocolA {
    var someVar: Any { get }
}

enum MyEnum<T: ProtocolA, U: ProtocolB> {
    case A(T)
    case B(U)
}

protocol DataObject {
    ...
}

extension DataObject where Self: ProtocolB {
    func doSomething() {
        let x = MyEnum.B(self)
        /// Compiler error:
        /// Cannot invoke 'B' with an argument list of type '(Self)'
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the above is giving me an error.
Strangely, removing either of the two enum generic constraints, leaving the enum with a single constraint, solves the problem...

Note that ProtocolB extends ProtocolA. Is this not supported when used with generic constraints?

---

**UPDATE**

Changing `MyEnum` to this solves the problem:

```
enum MyEnum {
    typealias T = ProtocolA
    typealias U = ProtocolB

    case A(T)
    case B(U)
}
```

However, I still don't quite get why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is a little misleading. Let's simplify the problem to explore it.

```
protocol ProtocolA {}

protocol ProtocolB: ProtocolA {}

enum MyEnum<T: ProtocolA, U: ProtocolB> {
    case A(T)
    case B(U)
}

struct AThing: ProtocolA {}

struct BThing: ProtocolB {}

let bThing = BThing()
let thing = MyEnum.B(bThing) // error: cannot invoke 'B' with an argument list of type '(BThing)'
```

So now we have the same problem without needing `DataObject`. Why does this fail?

`MyEnum` is generic. That means that in order to create a concrete type, it must know the types of `T` and `U`. You provided constraints on those types (one conforms to `ProtocolA` and the other to `ProtocolB`), but you didn't say specifically what types they are.

When we get to this line:

```
let thing = MyEnum.B(bThing)
```

What type is `thing`? With type inference, we can work out what `U` is, but what is `T`?

```
let thing: MyEnum<?, BThing> = MyEnum.B(bThing)
```

There's just not enough context here to work it out, so we have to tell the compiler explicitly:

```
let thing = MyEnum<AThing, BThing>.B(bThing)
```

So the full type of `thing` is `MyEnum<AThing, BThing>`, which is a different type than `MyEnum<OtherAThing, BThing>`. (Exactly like `[Int]` is different type than `[String]`, which is why `let xs = []` won't compile without an explicit type definition.)

Your second example that works is not generic, so there's no problem. It simplifies to:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A(ProtocolA)
    case B(ProtocolB)
}
```

Bound typealiases just rename types, they don't create new types (like an unbound typealias would, or as Swift 2.2 calls it, `associatedtype`). So we know that `A` takes any `ProtocolA` and `B` takes any `ProtocolB`, and all `MyEnum` instances have the same type.

The error is unfortunate because the compiler is confused. You'd get a clearer error if you simplified this down to the most basic case. This fails for exactly the same reason as your example.

```
enum MyEnum<T> {
    case A
}

let x = MyEnum.A // error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This is a gold answer I'd like to see more often here on SO ;) Indeed the error is very unfortunate here :)
I'll stick with the `typealias` solution for now. It still allows me to pass in any thing that conforms to the relevant protocol. (So kind of like the solution with generics). I guess this limits me to constraining the input to only a single protocol, rather than doing something like this: `<T where T: ProtocolA, T: ProtocolC>` ?

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting from that constraint. Do you mean "or?" If that were the case, what is the type of T? What methods can you call on it? It has to have one type. If there are some group of protocols that overlap, you can make another protocol that they all conform to.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have since moved to another solution. Thanks for your help anyways. However:
Please have a look at this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaXSbqo3iKA&t=2m54s
It says that it should work?